# If $\deg(f) > p^k$ then $f$ as an irreducible divisor of degree $> k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $p$ be prime and let $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$ with no repeated roots. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $\deg(f) > p^k$. Show that $f$ has an irreducible divisor of degree $> k$.

My  work so far: $f$ can not split over $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$. Now I'm stuck already.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there are no repeated roots?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is definitely what i meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the proposition is actually not correct. As a counterexample, consider
$$f = (x^8 - x) \cdot (x^2 + x + 1) = x (x-1) (x^2 + x + 1) (x^3 + x + 1) (x^3 + x^2 + 1)$$
over $\Bbb F_2$. It has degree $10 > 2^3$ and no repeated roots, yet all irreducible factors have degree $\le 3$ (the problem is that $x^2 + x + 1$ does *not* split in $\Bbb F_8$).

One proof strategy (for a salvage) would be the following: Consider all algebraic elements over $\Bbb F_p$ whose minimal polynomial (over $\Bbb F_p$) has degree $\le k$. If $f$ has no irreducible factor of degree $> k$ then all the roots of $f$ are among these algebraic elements. The worst-case clearly is when $f$ has all of these elements as its roots. Thus we must replace $p^k$ by the number of these algebraic elements. Clearly, $p + p^2 + \dots + p^k$ would work but the bound can definitely be made better (should not be too hard if you think a while about it, I don't have the time right now). In particular, $p^{k+1}$ is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm, the counterexample does seem to disprove the proposition, although my TA did asure me that it was true. How de we know so easily that our function has no repeated roots?

Comment: @Krijn You can take the derivative to check this.  Your TA probably got briefly confused: the polynomial $x^{p^k}-x$ is always the product of all irreducibles in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$ _whose degree divides $k$_.  This could easily be misremembered as _whose degree is $\leq k$_.  That would make this problem seem compelling, though flawed.

Comment: @Krijn The real conclusion we want to draw is that a polynomial with no repeated roots and degree $>p^k$ must have an irreducible factor whose degree does not divide $k$.  This is the cleanest way to salvage this, in my opinion.

Comment: That seals the deal for me. I had proven that last statement, so apparently the syllabus was wrong, and I wasn't, which was of course more unlikely than the opposite. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For every $l\in\mathbb{N}$, the extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}/\mathbb{F}_p$ is normal, thus every irreducible polynomial of degree $l$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$. Assume that all irreducible components of $f$ are of degree $\leq k$, then each one of them splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, thus $f$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, which is impossible, as you observed yourself.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was close to that but did not consider that every irreducible polynomial of degree k had to split!

Comment: I'm afraid sanktoras has a point... The fact that $f$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ does *not* imply $f$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k+1}}$. So my proof, as it is, does not work. Considering the example in sanctoras' answer, are you sure the claim holds?

Comment: I'm still looking at his counterexample, but this is from a textbook, and my TA assured me that it was true (I was skeptic at first, too).

Comment: It is certainly true that there is an irreducible factor of degree $\ge k$ (instead of $> k$), but then the bound on $\deg f$ could be made much better ...